# CSS translate3d crop text

Tags: css, css-transforms

CSS translate3d crop text in Chrome and iOS chrome.

Chrome crop after: `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);`

But I don't understand why.

http://jsfiddle.net/zspr5j89/1/

Thanks!